# How to track emails sent using google app script?

Tags: email, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I use google sheets to track sales contacts. I use a simple [google app script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails) to automatically send emails to all the people listed in the spreadsheet.

I also use services like [streak](http://streak.com/) and [mailtrack](https://mailtrack.io/en/) to track my emails (ie know that it the recipient has viewed it)

The problem is that both these plugins are chrome extensions. So I noticed that they work fine if I send an email manually through gmail on chrome. However when I send mass emails using the above script, these tracker tools are oblivious.

Any ideas?

## Update

I tried sending the email using [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app), but didn't work either:

```
  GmailApp.sendEmail(testEmail, subject,'sample body', {
    htmlBody: message
  });
```

Comment: I noticed that your link went to a function that was using MailApp.  Perhaps if you used GmailApp your tracking programs may work for you.

Comment: @Cooper tried it, didn't work (see question update)

Comment: Bro , have you solved this issue?

Comment: Any progress on it? I need same thing.